# Objective-C JSON to TableView very slow

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I have a question. I get JSON from my URL it looks like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)parseObject:(NSString *)object withKey:(NSInteger)key {
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *randomKey = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"randomKey"];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"object"];
NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:key];

NSArray *myWords = [[loan objectForKey:object] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

return myWords;
}
```

To my TableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[self parseObject:@"bedrijfsnaam" withKey:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self parseObject:@"leverunix" withKey:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
}
```

It loads really slowly and I have a sort of lag when I want to scroll. What can I do to make this better?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you fetch the JSON data from the server *each time* that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. That must be slow!

You should fetch the data only once (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`), deserialize the JSON
 and store the result in some property of the view controller, so that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can get the objects from there.

Comment: I have an array in viewDidLoad and put all my data in that array, it works perfect now. Thanks

Comment: More generally, you're performing a blocking operation on the main thread, which means that the cell isn't created until the JSON response is received and parsed. If the server takes 30 seconds to respond, your app will be unresponsive for 30 seconds!!!

Comment: @HenkdeBoer: You are welcome. - But have also a look at timthetoolman's answer. Even a single URL request might take a long time, so fetching the data asynchronously (or in a background thread) to avoid the main UI blocked is also good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

is causing the main thread to block while it is retrieving the data from the web URL.

Try using an asynchronous method. It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)parseObject:(NSString *)object withKey:(NSInteger)key
```

again and again in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

This should not happen.

Try to have your data in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear and then save that data in a global variable.

Now call any function which will get the data from that variable and return the required value.

Comment: any variable local to class